# Default Activity not found, Gradle.kts Compose Jetpack

Tags: build.gradle, android-jetpack

I use gradle.ks when I add this dependencies, I can not run app because Default Activity not found.
But in another project with usual gradle(groove) it works normally

```
  implementation ("androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev02")
implementation ("androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev02")
implementation ("androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev02")
```

I use this : distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : I had to set minSdkVersion = 21!